# Finding properties of Poincare Transformation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, inertial-frames, group-theory, poincare-symmetry

I have started studying the Poincare group for the first time, in preparation for my first QFT course, and I wish to be able to solve the following problem:

> A Poincare transformation ($\Lambda,a)$ can be written as:
>   $$x'^{\mu}=\Lambda_{\nu}^{\mu}x^{\nu}+a^{\mu}$$
>   Determine the multiplication rule, ($\Lambda_1,a_1)$($\Lambda_2,a_2)$, as well as the inverse and unity element in this group.

I know that this is very basic, but it is probably because of it that I have not been able to find an explanation for beginners as to how to do it.

I know that the multiplication rule means that the multiplication of two elements of the group must still be a member of the group, but I don't know how to start proving it.

Similarly, I know the definitions of unity element and inverse, but I am lost as to how to begin working on this problem. Could you please point the way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to not get lost with too many indices let's define
$x'$, $x$ and $a$ as column vectors (with 4 elements)
and $\Lambda$ as a matrix (with 4x4 elements).

Then the Poincaré transformation
$$ x'^{\mu}=\Lambda^{\mu}{}_{\nu}x^{\nu}+a^{\mu} $$
can be written more concisely (by using matrix multiplication
and vector addition) as
$$x'=\Lambda x +a.$$

> I know that the multiplication rule means that the
>    multiplication of two elements of the group must still
>    be a member of the group, but I don't know how to start proving it.

Consider a first Poincaré transformation $(\Lambda_1,a_1)$ as
$$x'=\Lambda_1 x + a_1, \tag{1}$$
and a second Poincaré transformation $(\Lambda_2,a_2)$ as
$$x''=\Lambda_2 x' + a_2. \tag{2}$$
You get the composition by inserting (1) into (2):
$$\begin{align}
 x''&=\Lambda_2 (\Lambda_1 x + a_1) + a_2 \\
 &= \Lambda_2 \Lambda_1 x + \Lambda_2 a_1 + a_2
\end{align}$$
Now it has the form $x''= \Lambda x + a$ with
$$(\Lambda,a)_{\text{composed}} = (\Lambda_2\Lambda_1,\Lambda_2 a_1 + a_2).$$

> Similarly, I know the definitions of unity element and
>    inverse, but I am lost as to how to begin working on this
>    problem. Could you please point the way?

The unity transformation is simply
$$x'=x.$$
You can rewrite this as
$$x'=\mathbf{I} x + \mathbf{0},$$
where $\mathbf{I}$ is the unity matrix ($\Lambda^{\mu}{}_{\nu}=\delta^\mu_\nu$)
and $\mathbf{0}$ is the null vector ($a^\nu=0$).
Now it has the form $x'= \Lambda x + a$ with
$$(\Lambda,a)_{\text{unity}}=(\mathbf{I}, \mathbf{0}).$$

---

You can find the inverse transformation of
$$ x' = \Lambda x + a$$
by resolving this equation for $x$:
$$\begin{align}
x &= \Lambda^{-1}(x'-a) \\
 &= \Lambda^{-1}x'-\Lambda^{-1}a
\end{align}$$
where $\Lambda^{-1}$ is the inverse matrix of $\Lambda$.
Now it has the form $x= \Lambda x' + a$ with
$$(\Lambda,a)_{\text{inv}}=(\Lambda^{-1},-\Lambda^{-1} a).$$

Answer (score 1):

The element $(\Lambda, a)$ can be seen as a function, let's call it $g_{\Lambda,a}$
$$
\begin{aligned}
g_{\Lambda,a} : \;\;\mathbb{R}^{1,3} &\to \mathbb{R}^{1,3}\\
\quad x^\mu &\to\Lambda^\mu_{\phantom{\mu}\nu}\,x^\nu + a^\mu \,. 
\end{aligned} 
$$
This is a *representation* of the group.${}^1$ Representations are useful because we can do explicit computations with them and prove abstract properties of the group. A representation is fully specified only if we also say what does the group product $(\Lambda_1,a_1)\cdot (\Lambda_2,a_2)$ map to in this space. Obviously the answer is: function composition $g_{\Lambda_1,a_1} \circ g_{\Lambda_2,a_2}$.

We need to compute the following composition: $g_{\Lambda_1,a_1} \circ g_{\Lambda_2,a_2}$
$$
\begin{aligned}
x^\mu \;\;&\overset{g_{\Lambda_2,a_2}}{\longrightarrow}\;\;
(\Lambda_2)^\mu_{\phantom{\mu}\nu}\,x^\nu + a_2^\mu \equiv y^\mu\\
\;\;&\overset{g_{\Lambda_1,a_1}}{\longrightarrow}\;\;
(\Lambda_1)^\mu_{\phantom{\mu}\nu}\,y^\nu + a_1^\mu = \\
&\quad\;\, = (\Lambda_1)^\mu_{\phantom{\mu}\nu}\,((\Lambda_2)^\nu_{\phantom{\nu}\rho}\,x^\rho + a_2^\nu) + a_1^\mu = \\
&\quad\;\, = (\Lambda_1\cdot \Lambda_2)^\mu_{\phantom{\mu}\rho}\,x^\rho + (\Lambda_1)^\mu_{\phantom{\mu}\nu}\,a_2^\nu + a_1^\mu\,.
\end{aligned}
$$
Now with $\cdot$ I mean plain simple matrix multiplication. I could also rename $\rho\to\nu$ in the last line. The task now is finding an element of the group $(\Lambda_?,a_?) \leftrightarrow g_{\Lambda_?,a_?}$ that does the exact same job
$$
\begin{aligned}
x^\mu \;\;&\overset{g_{\Lambda_?,a_?}}{\longrightarrow}\;\;(\Lambda_?)^\mu_{\phantom{\mu}\nu}\,x^\nu + a_?^\mu\\
&\quad\;\, = (\Lambda_1\cdot \Lambda_2)^\mu_{\phantom{\mu}\nu}\,x^\nu + (\Lambda_1)^\mu_{\phantom{\mu}\nu}\,a_2^\nu + a_1^\mu\,.
\end{aligned}
$$
This equation is easily solved to
$$
(\Lambda_?)^\mu_{\phantom{\mu}\nu} = (\Lambda_1 \cdot \Lambda_2)^\mu_{\phantom{\mu}\nu}\,,\qquad
a_?^\mu = (\Lambda_1)^\mu_{\phantom{\mu}\nu}\,a_2^\nu + a_1^\mu\,.
$$
And this will be true in the abstract sense, not just in this particular representation, therefore we can say
$$
(\Lambda_1,a_1)\cdot (\Lambda_2,a_2) = (\Lambda_1\cdot \Lambda_2, \,\Lambda_1 \cdot a_2 + a_1)\,.
$$

---

$\quad{}^1$ Representations are actually linear transformations (endomorphisms) on a vector space. What we have is an affine transformation because of the translation piece $a^\mu$. But it's well known that we can still represent this as a linear transformation on the [projective space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation#Representation).